# How replace json value with JSON_REPLACE in MySql 5.7 in many paths with one query?

Tags: php, mysql, json

[This is my JSON document](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=45622644d1826049686c5aa9fe33034f)

How to replace all "`c-3`" to "`my_value_1234`" with `JSON_REPLACE` in "`id-1`" with ONE query ?

```
UPDATE t SET j = JSON_REPLACE(j, $."id-1"."a-1"."b-2"."c-3", "1234")
```

This query is working but it changes value in only one place. I wanted use wildcard * or ** but it doesn't work with `JSON_REPLACE`.

Comment: I have tried, with the manual, to write an Update+JSON_REPLACE. The code has worked for the specific path. However, I can't find any information/hints, how to do REPLACE simultaneously in many places, in my JSON code. According to manual in JSON_REPLACE, I can't use "* or ** wildcard". I don't have any idea how to cope with it, maybe I just lack of experience. That's why, your help would be very appreciated :-)

Comment: So the problem is with it replacing only a single instance of that match? And you need it to replace all? Add those details into your question.